# When .html is used to get a jQuery content , Ithe content loses jQuery functions. 

Tags: jquery, html, dom, indexing

```
<div id="mainContent">
<div class="photoShow"></div>
<div class="photo_nav"></div>
<div class="photo_caption">
<div class="photo_caption_content"></div>
</div>

// .photo_content has jQuery content and photo background
<div id="content">
<div class="photo_content"></div>
<div class="photo_content"></div>
<div class="photo_content"></div>
</div>

  <script>
  $('.photo_nav a.photo_nav_item').click(function(){
var navClicked = $(this).index();
var Photo = $('.photo_content').get(navClicked);
var curPhoto = $(Photo).html();
  $(".photo_nav a.photo_nav_item").removeClass('current');
  $(".photoShow").removeClass('current');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$(".photoShow").fadeIn('slow', 'swing');
$(".photoShow").html(curPhoto);
   });
  </script>

  // .photo_content has jQuery properties which runs fine by itself. But with this click      //function, it loses the properties. Using .get, instead of .html i.e. 


 $(".photoShow").get(Photo); 

 //keeps the contents working but then I lose navigation index property.
 //in conclusion, with .html, it displays correct .photo_content but DOM does not work.
 //With .get, I get .photo_content that works but indexing does not work.
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please try to describe your problem better.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% clear on the question. But .get() and .html() return fundamentally different things.

.get() returns a DOM element

.html() returns (or sets) a string of HTML content.

Also note that this would not make sense:

```
$(".photoShow").get(Photo);
```

Unless Photo was an integer, which according to your code it isn't.

Does that help?  If not - which line of your posted code isn't doing what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

i think you are making some confusion:

[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) returns the html content of the first matched selector. so if you have:

```
<div id='container'><div id='content'>Content</div></div>

$('#container').html();//returns <div id="content">Content</div> which is a string
```

[get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) retruns a dom element

```
<div id='container'><div id='content'>Content</div></div>

$('#container').get(0);//returns a dom object
```